# Ionic Angularjs ui-calendar fetching the event based on month

Tags: android, angularjs, fullcalendar, ionic-framework

Hi I am new to angularjs i am try to use jquery full-calendar http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ of the angular version. My question is I am able to fetch all event on load.,  Is it possible to fetch the event of click on next or prev (Based on the month to fetch the event of that particular month)?

Code for fetch the event on load

```
var calCurrentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
$scope.init = function() {
        console.log('this is the new calCurrentDate'+calCurrentDate);

        $ionicLoading.show({template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i>'});
        var req = {
            method: 'GET', 
            url: link+'meal/calendar?api_token='+$localStorage.accessToken+'&start_date='+calCurrentDate+'&id=',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }
        console.log(req);
        $http(req).success(function(data) { 
            $scope.schedule = data.dayplan;
            for(i in $scope.schedule) {
                $scope.events.push({
                    id: $scope.schedule[i].id,
                    title: '.',
                    start:   $scope.schedule[i].day,
                    color: $scope.schedule[i].color_code
                });
            }
            $ionicLoading.hide(); 
        }).error(function(data) { 
            console.log(data.message); 
            $ionicLoading.hide(); 
        });
    };
```

And on click on the next or prev i am able to get the month and date and i am try like this

```
$scope.renderView = function(view){    
    var date = new Date(view.calendar.getDate());
    $scope.arrowDate = $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if($scope.arrowDate != calCurrentDate){
        calCurrentDate = $scope.arrowDate;
        $scope.init(calCurrentDate);
    }
};
```

and also tried like this also

```
$scope.renderView = function(view){    
    var date = new Date(view.calendar.getDate());
    $scope.arrowDate = $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if($scope.arrowDate != calCurrentDate){
        $ionicLoading.show({template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i>'});
        var req = {
            method: 'GET', 
            url: link+'meal/calendar?api_token='+$localStorage.accessToken+'&start_date='+$scope.arrowDate+'&id=',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }
        console.log($scope.arrowDate);
        $http(req).success(function(data) { 
            $scope.schedule = data.dayplan;
            for(i in $scope.schedule) {
                $scope.events.push({
                    id: $scope.schedule[i].id,
                    title: '.',
                    start:   $scope.schedule[i].day,
                    color: $scope.schedule[i].color_code
                });
            }
            $ionicLoading.hide(); 
        }).error(function(data) { 
            console.log(data.message); 
            $ionicLoading.hide(); 
        });
    }
};
```

and the problem is it fetch the data but it goes back to the current month 
(eg: if the current month is February if i click next i able fetch the data of the March but it comes back to February rather than staying in the March ) Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer issue was with the $scope.event.push here how i sloved

```
if($scope.arrowDate != calCurrentDate){
            $ionicLoading.show({template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i>'});
            var req = {
                method: 'GET', 
                url: link+'meal/calendar?api_token='+$localStorage.accessToken+'&start_date='+$scope.arrowDate+'&id=',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }

            $http(req).success(function(data) { 
                console.log(data.message); 
                $scope.schedule = data.dayplan;
                var tmpEvent = [];
                for(i in $scope.schedule) {
                    tmpEvent.push({
                        id: $scope.schedule[i].id,
                        title: '.',
                        start:   $scope.schedule[i].day,
                        color: $scope.schedule[i].color_code
                    });
                }
                uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', tmpEvent); 
                $scope.fetchMeal($scope.arrowDate);
                $ionicLoading.hide(); 
            }).error(function(data) { 
                console.log(data.message); 
                $ionicLoading.hide(); 
            });
        }
```